# Notation for weak limit

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence

I have just learned weak convergence, that is defined as follows:

**Definition**
Let $X$ be a Banach space, $\{x_n\}\subset X$ be a sequence, and $x\in X$. $\{x_n\}$ is said to be weakly convergent to $x$ if $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ for any $f\in X^*$.

And we use the notation $x_n \buildrel{w}\over{\to} x$ for weak convergence.

What I was wondering is that, **is there a commonly accepted notation for the weak limit that corresponds to $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}$?** I thought it would be convenient to have one, but my textbook or any information on the internet does not talk about this issue. Is there a mathematical reason for why we don't have one (if there isn't), or is it just tradition?

Comment: $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ is also fairly common.

Comment: Are you aware of $x_n \rightharpoonup x$?

Comment: @SahibaArora I am aware of that notation, but that is not the point of the question. We can say $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n =x$ instead of $x_n \to x$, then what I was wondering was that, is there a similar notation for weak limit, like, $\textrm{weaklim}_{n\to \infty}x_n = x$ as an alternative to  $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ or $x_n \buildrel{w}\over{\to} x$?

Comment: @Kaira $w-\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n =x$ is also used in some texts.

Comment: @SahibaArora Thanks, that is what I was looking for. maybe make it to an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the notation $$w-\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n =x$$ is used in certain places. One reference I could quickly find for this was [Functional Analysis by K. Yosida](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540586548).